# apt-get not working for ubuntu 16.10

Tags: apt

Using ubuntu 16.10 on 32bit computer.

Have a following sources.list in etc/apt

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main restricted universe 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-security main restricted universe 
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted universe 
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-proposed main restricted universe 
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-backports main restricted universe
```

and it gives me following error on `sudo apt-get update`

```
    Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-on-rails/ppa/ubuntu yakkety/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                    
Fetched 102 kB in 7s (14.2 kB/s)                                                                                                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-on-rails/ppa/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://deb.playonlinux.com/dists/precise/InRelease: Signature by key 74F7358425EEB6176094C884E0F72778C4676186 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-on-rails/ppa/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: tried this solution but not helps me http://askubuntu.com/questions/586369/sudo-apt-get-update-not-working

Comment: yes @karel your link worked for me